# Vim – move a block by relative line number not performing as expected

Tags: vim

I'm visually selecting a block of code (scss) in Vim and trying to move it to appear after line 6.

After visually selecting the lines, the command I am using is: <kbd>m -6</kbd>

However, the lines aren't actually being moved as I expect. See this Gif of the result:

[image]

Do you see how the result ends up a line out? My understanding is that the move command should move the block of selected code *after* the line specified?

So the code would look this after the move command:

```
&.on-Grey_C7 {

}
&.on-Grey_BB {
    border: 1px solid brighten($color-yellow, -31);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To move the block after the a specific line number is actually: `m {line-number}`. In your case it would be `m 6` after block selection. [this is a good read](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you've created the linewise visual selection from top to bottom, and your cursor is on line 173, when you execute an Ex command (like `:move`) on the range, the cursor will jump back to the beginning of the selection (i.e. line 171), and therefore, your offset is wrong (`'<,'>m -4` is right).

To avoid having to mentally adjust the offset, you can use the `o` command in visual mode (before entering the command-line with `:`) to move the cursor to the start of the selection.

Comment: where is the cursor in visual selection makes no different for move. that is, with or without pressing `o` in visual selection, it leads the same output.

Comment: Great, understand why it's doing it now, thanks. However, even now I understand, that still seems a little 'off' and unintuitive to me. Are there any benefits in Vim working this way? As a related question, would it be possible to hijack the move command in this context so that is automatically makes the adjustment?

Comment: @Kent: Yes, but moving the cursor avoids having to account for this phenomenon; with `'relativenumber'`, you can just read off the amount of lines to move.

Comment: I think this has benefits for macros and mappings, to start from a consistent position. You could define a custom `:Move` command that accounts for that, but I would recommend just accepting this, as other commands are affected by this, too.

Comment: @IngoKarkat oh, it seems that I misunderstood your answer... you meant from the "current" ln - offset. You are right.

Comment: @BenFrain if the lines you want to move and the move target position on same screen, you could first move to the target position, then `:171,173m.` in this way, you don't have to count, but you need turn relativeln off. If the part you want to move outside the screen, or it is big block, better use mark or even `d` and `p` to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: @Kent thanks. TBH I'll just remember to use <kbd>o</kbd> when I select and move in this manner. In MacVim my <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> solves this for some reason (I have to investigate) it doesn't work well in iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

it worked correct, you didn't understand the adress well.

```
:'<,'>m -6
```

moves your block under the line with number of `(your 1st selected line number -6)`

In your case, your first selected line num is `171`, so your blocked was moved under line: 171-6=165, which started with 166. vim does it exactly right.

in your case, you should do:

```
:'<,'>m 6
```

which moves your block under line (absolute line#) 6

to understand the address, `:h address` You can also open a new buffer, do a `!!seq 20`, then play a little bit.